# Calculate time difference only considering hours

Tags: python

I want to calculate the time difference in hour not considering the date.

For example I want the difference between `22:00:00` and `01:00:00` to be `3`.

The code I got so far:

```py
time1 = datetime.strptime("22:00:00", '%H:%M:%S')
time2 = datetime.strptime("01:00:00", '%H:%M:%S')
res = time1-time2
print(res)
```

The output I got: `21:00:00`

The output I want: `3`

Comment: Well the question here is weather 22 is before or after 01. It depends are you talking about the time from 22 until the next 01, or the time from 01 to the next 22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot extract the hours directly from the resulting `timedelta` object, as they keep fraction-of-day as seconds, so a simple workaround is to take the seconds and calculate the hours from there.

Also note that you want to subtract `time1` to `time2`, otherwise you will get `21` hours:

```
(time2 - time1).seconds/3600
# 3
```